# Changing class name of a div doesn't update it's appearance in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to toggle background of a div with changing `className` every second based on changing the state of a data array.
As `console.log(grid[0][0])` informs me, it actually changes the grid array data, but it doesn't update `div` after the first iteration. [I provided props wiith `<App row={5} col={10}/>` in `index.js`.]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App(props) {
  // Initializing the grid.
  let grid = initializeGrid(props.row, props.col);

  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState(grid);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setGridData(gridData => updateGrid(gridData));
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {gridData.reduce(function (acc, itm, idx) {
        let item = itm.map((cell, index) => <div key={acc.length + index} className={cell.state ? "state-on" : "state-off"}>{acc.length + index}</div>);
        return acc.concat(item);
      }, [])}
    </div>
  );
}

function initializeGrid(row, col) {
  let cell = { state: false, count: 0 }
  let grid = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < row; y++) {
    grid.push([]);
    for (let x = 0; x < col; x++) {
      grid[y].push(cell);
    }
  }
  return grid;
}

function updateGrid(grid) {
  let currentState = grid[0][0].state;
  currentState ? (grid[0][0] = { state: false, count: 0 }) : (grid[0][0] = { state: true, count: 0 });
  console.log(grid[0][0]);
  return grid;
}

export default App;
```

`App.css`:

```
html, body, #root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ffeead;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 80px);
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #ffeead;
}

.state-off {
  background-color: #96ceb4;
}

.state-on {
  background-color: #ff6f69;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code using codesandbox or other similar websites?

Comment: I think your changes are not saved. I just see an empty react template.

Comment: I saved now. https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-glade-b16n7y

Comment: If you remove `StrictMode`, you'll see your code works just fine.

Comment: Thank you, it's working, it was so frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating your state. Which is discouraged.
In strict mode, `updateGrid` runs twice, so `state` of cell will toggle twice. Hence you see no changes.

`updateGrid` function should not mutate your state. It should be something like this:

```
function updateGrid(grid) {
  let currentState = grid[0][0].state;
  currentState
    ? (grid[0][0] = { state: false, count: 0 })
    : (grid[0][0] = { state: true, count: 0 });

  const grid0 = [{ ...grid[0][0], state: currentState }, ...grid[0].slice(1)];
  const newGrid = [grid0, ...grid.slice(1)];

  return newGrid;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-flower-cxt2md?file=/src/App.js)